# What would be the Unicode character for big bullet in the middle of the character?

Tags: unicode

I want something like

```
0x2022  8226    BULLET  •
```

But bigger.

I can't even seem to find them at http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html

What should I search for? Dots? bullets?

Answer (score 271, accepted):

http://www.unicode.org is the place to look for symbol names.

```
● BLACK CIRCLE        25CF
⚫ MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE 26AB
⬤ BLACK LARGE CIRCLE  2B24
```

or even:

```
 NEW MOON SYMBOL   1F311
```

Good luck finding a font that supports them all.  Only one shows up in Windows 7 with Chrome.

Comment: These links contain some more info like HTML entities for these four characters: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cf/ http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26ab/ http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b24/ http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f311/

Comment: Beware of semantics under various fonts (if that is beyond your control on receivers device): A circle will (should) always be a circle in any font. A bullet might be a square or even a brush stroke depending on font family... there's certainly even more leeway for interpretation of „new moon“...

Comment: It looks like another inherited thing: the Medium ⚫ is larger than the Large ⬤! Came here on an attempt to find something larger than the Large Circle and what a surprise - it turned out to be the Medium Circle! =) Thank you, Mark!

Comment: @Mar This depends on your environment. E.g. in Windows 10's Notepad, Large Circle is bigger than Medium. But not in Chrome on the same OS.

Comment: remember to write it like "\u2B24" in your strings

Answer (score 199):

Here's a full list of black dotlike characters from Unicode:

| number | character | HTML entity | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U+00B7 | · | `&#183;` | Middle Dot |
| U+25CF | ● | `&#9679;` | Black Circle |
| U+23FA | ⏺ | `&#9210;` | Black Circle for Record Emoji |
| U+26AB | ⚫ | `&#9899;` | Medium Black Circle Emoji |
| U+2B24 | ⬤ | `&#11044;` | Black Large Circle |
| U+29ED | ⧭ | `&#10733;` | Black Circle with Down Arrow |
| U+1F784 |  | `&#128900;` | Black Slightly Small Circle |
| U+2022 | • | `&#8226;` | Black Small Circle |
| U+2219 | ∙ | `&#8729;` | Bullet Operator |
| U+22C5 | ⋅ | `&#8901;` | Dot Operator |
| U+1F311 |  | `&#127761;` | New Moon Symbol Emoji |
| U+30FB | ・ | `&#12539;` | Katakana Middle Dot |

Answer (score 32):

You can use a span with 50% border radius.

```css
 .mydot{
     background: rgb(66, 183, 42);
     border-radius: 50%;
     display: inline-block;
     height: 20px;
     margin-left: 4px;
     margin-right: 4px;
     width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="mydot"></span>
```

Comment: I like this solution, slower but you can control position and size or color more directly.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius The question doesn't specify this being about website building so a HTML/CSS answer is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 23):

You can search for “bullet” when using e.g. BabelPad (which has a Character Map where you can search by character name), but you will hardly find anything larger than U+2022 BULLET (though the size depends on font). Searching for “circle” finds many characters, too many, as the string appears in so many names. The largest simple circle is probably U+25CF BLACK CIRCLE “●”. If it’s too large U+26AB MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE “⚫” might be suitable.

Beware that few fonts contain these characters.

A new problem has emerged with characters like MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE, a problem that you may well see above. As noted in a comment, this character may look (much) larger than BLACK CIRCLE. The reason is that it may be rendered in “emoji style” as opposite to “text style”; this is explicitly mentioned in an annotation for the character in the Unicode Standard. In principle, you can use a Variation Selector (VS15 or VS16) character after the character to specify the style, but in practice it probably does not work. An explicit selection of font, e.g. Segoe UI Symbol (instead of Segoe UI Emoji) tends to be more successful.

Comment: Note that on many systems the _Medium Black Circle Emoji_ (⚫) is actually larger than the _Black Circle_ (●).

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows (Any Version)

Go to start -> then search character map

that's where you will find 1000s of characters with their Unicode
in the advance view you can get more options that you can use for different encoding symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the already mentioned [official Unicode site](http://www.unicode.org/) (which I personally find difficult to use), I frequently use the following websites to search for Unicode characters:

- https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm

  ([view](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm)  character info,
  [search](https://www.fileformat.info/search/google.htm?q=bullet) for "bullet")
- https://unicode-table.com/

  ([view](https://unicode-table.com/en/2022/) character info, [search](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=bullet) for "bullet")
- https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/

  ([view](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+20AC) character info, [search](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/search?q=bullet) for "bullet")

All three sites contain basic information about each character (such as Unicode codepoint, several encodings and HTML entities, different names for the character, Unicode version, etc.). They also have a search function that allows you to search by character name or number.

The first one also shows how to use the character in C/C++/Java or Python source code, and has a [test page](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/browsertest.htm) for browser support of each character.

The second one has a nice "copy" button that allows you to directly copy the Unicode character to clipboard, which may be convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the font in use, the "Z notation spot" [<sup>1</sup>](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2981) [<sup>2</sup>](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2981) might be what you're looking for.

I'm going to use markdown and redundant unordered lists to provide the best visual guide I can:

> - ⟸ rendered via markdown for unordered lists
>
> ```
> ⦁ ⟸ `U+2981` Z notation spot
> • ⟸ `U+2022` bullet / &bull;
> • ⟸ `U+2219` bullet operator
> ● ⟸ `U+25CF` black circle
> ```
>
> - ⟸ rendered via markdown for unordered lists
>
> > ⦁  ⟸ `U+2981` Z notation spot
> > •  ⟸ `U+2022` bullet / `&bull;`
> > •  ⟸ `U+2219` bullet operator
> > ● ⟸ `U+25CF` black circle
>
> - ⟸ rendered via markdown for unordered lists

Assuming you're seeing the same thing I'm seeing, in the Monospace font, the Z notation spot is slightly smaller, but in the normal font, the Z notation spot is slightly bigger.

However, in Discord, here's all those same characters again:

[image]

As you can see, here, the Z notation spot outside the codeblock as well as the black circle inside the codeblock are almost the same size as the bullet rendered by the unordered list.

Hopefully this was helpful to someone. I didn't see any mention of the Z notation spot in search results regarding filled circles in Unicode – I only found out about it from using [shapecatcher](https://shapecatcher.com) (great tool, by the way).