# Add bullet point to JavaFX label

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

Is it possible to add a bullet point to the start of a JavaFX label?

Here is basic FXML for a label

```
<Label fx:id="lblTerm1" text="Label" wrapText="true" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
```

It outputs something like this

My Name

I would like something like

- My Name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include a bullet in the text being displayed on the label using unicode character.

```
0x2022  8226    BULLET  •
```

If you are looking for something larger, you can look into this:
[What would be the Unicode character for big bullet in the middle of the character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971187/what-would-be-the-unicode-character-for-big-bullet-in-the-middle-of-the-characte)

Hope this helps.

Comment: And is there anyway of putting this in the text of the label from FXML?  I have tried setting the text to \u2022, which works fine if i do it in code, but not via FXML file

Comment: Use a character entity:  `<Label text="&#x2022; My Name"/>`