# Default glyphs for CSS list style types

Tags: html, css, unicode

I'm looking for the exact glyphs that are used in the default implementation of the various CSS list style types, e.g. bullets, circles etc. As suggested by the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style-type), the "exact rendering depends on the user agent", so the answer seems to depend on the used browser. My question still is what font/Unicode points are used for these symbols, or if they are rendered differently, how would you get a result that is as close as possible to the original symbols?

The problem I'm trying to solve is to have lists where different items (in the same list) may have different symbols. In [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36743430) they list several Unicode symbols for the bullet, but they all look different for me than the default implementation (in Firefox), even if resized they have a slightly different form or aren't anti-aliased and such.

Apologies if this seems pedantic to you. ;)

---

EDIT: [Here is a small example](https://jsfiddle.net/ebhye97v/) showing the problem. The Unicode symbols were added like this:

```
li.a:before {
  content: "\25CF";
  font-size: 82%;
}

li.b:before {
  content: "\25CB";
  font-size: 85%;
}
```

However, the symbols don't look like the defaults used for lists, and the question is how to make them look identically.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be off-topic, as it is question about browser implementations, and a very broad question at that (since there are so many browsers, including platform and version variation). It is not clear what the real problem is. Of course you can make different items (in the same list) have different symbols, rather simply. You don’t need to know browser defaults in order to do that.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The question aims for a solution that looks exactly like the default implementation