# How to increase inputType password dot size in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I have an `EditText` whose `inputType` is `numberPassword`. I want to change the dot size which replaces the text. It is quite small(android default) for my purpose. I want to increase the dot size. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: That is like replacing dot with asterisk. @ADM

Comment: Exactly! this was just for reference to get some idea from .i didn't say that its the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to replace asterisk with this ascii codes.
⚫ - ⚫ - Medium Black Circle
⬤ - &#11044 - Black Large Circle

[What would be the Unicode character for big bullet in the middle of the character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971187/what-would-be-the-unicode-character-for-big-bullet-in-the-middle-of-the-characte)

```
 public class MyPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
}; 

text.setTransformationMethod(new MyPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Answer (score 9):

The solution provided half works, the problem is that that transformation will transform the text directly to the '*' while the expected behavior is to hide the char once a new char has been input or after a few seconds so the user gets the chance to see the real char before hiding it. If you want to keep the default behavior you should do something like this:

```
/**
 * A transformation to increase the size of the dots displayed in the text.
 */
private object BiggerDotPasswordTransformationMethod : PasswordTransformationMethod() {

    override fun getTransformation(source: CharSequence, view: View): CharSequence {
        return PasswordCharSequence(super.getTransformation(source, view))
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence(
        val transformation: CharSequence
    ) : CharSequence by transformation {
        override fun get(index: Int): Char = if (transformation[index] == DOT) {
            BIGGER_DOT
        } else {
            transformation[index]
        }
    }

    private const val DOT = '\u2022'
    private const val BIGGER_DOT = '●'
}
```

This will replace the original dot with whatever char you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler in kotlin. You don't need to create a separate class just to override a single method. In kotlin, you can do this:

```kotlin
val passwordTransformation =  object: PasswordTransformationMethod() {
                    override fun getTransformation(
                        source: CharSequence?,
                        view: View?
                    ): CharSequence {
                        return super.getTransformation(source, view).replace(Regex("\u2022"), "●")
                    }
                }
```

Use it like this:

```kotlin
textView?.transformationMethod = passwordTransformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="password"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```