# How to show Unicode character in a TextView in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, unicode

I wanted to show Unicode in a text view in my android app. I searched for a solution but nothing really helped.
I wanted to do this programmatically in `Kotlin` as I want to concatenate it with the data that I fetch from Firestore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse unicode from html to string by using `HTML` library like

```
val bullet = "&#8226"
print("this is bullet a ${Html.fromHtml(bullet)}")
```

Comment: I wanted to use a big bullet which I got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36743430/13935956 it might be helpful if anybody is looking for it.

Comment: `Html.fromHtml(bullet)` is deprecated since Android N. Use `Html.fromHtml(bullet,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)` instead. See [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904739/html-fromhtml-deprecated-in-android-n)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check that font you use supports Unicode.
Then you can use `Html.fromHtml` as @Anshul advised but keep in mind that it is deprecated and you need to use `Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY` as it was advised in [Unicode characters not displayed in TextView.setText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522337/unicode-characters-not-displayed-in-textview-settext)